# Sequence Lemma explanation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

[image]

> Then every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point of $A$.

So I don't see it happening unless $X$ is a metric space, but the proof is for any topological space.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what does $x_n\to x$ mean?

Comment: It means $x_n$ converges to $x$

Comment: I am asking why is the greyed line true.

Comment: Yes, I know. What does "$x_n$ converges to $x$" mean? Definition?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convergent_Sequence/Topology

Comment: Duh, thanks. I know what convergence of a sequence means. It think for **jip** to write out the definition in words would be a good start to understanding why the greyed line is true. It is pretty much immediate from the definition.

Comment: @Aram, oh so there is no math, this is just definition...

Comment: Definition are part of math. Understanding the definitions is a good start to understanding math.

Comment: Well no, I know it make sense if we put a metric on it, but kind of hard for me to swallow if it just in a general topological space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That follows immediately from the definition of convergence of a sequence.

> Let $X$ be any topological space, $\sigma=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ a sequence in $X$, and $x\in X$. Then by definition $\sigma$ converges to to $x$ if and only if for each nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is an $n_U\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_k\in U$ for all $k\ge n_U$.

In your case we’re *assuming* that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to x$, so by definition every nbhd $U$ of $x$ not only contains at least one $x_n$, but actually contains all terms of the sequence from some point on. Since by hypothesis the sequence lies entirely in $A$, every nbhd of $x$ therefore must contain at least one point of $A$.

Comment: Okay, so this is a definition, then I can't question it...

Comment: To be honest, there is an intermediate step which is that a point x is in thr adherence of A if and only if every nbhd of x has a non empty intersection with A. Once you've shown this the sequence lemma follows.

Comment: @StatisticDean: No intermediate step is needed.