# The use of the Axiom of Choice in this proof of the sequence lemma

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

[image: Proof of sequence lemma]

Here is a proof of the sequence lemma I lifted from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986863/sequence-lemma-explanation). It seems to me naively that the axiom of choice is being used to selected the $x_n$'s. Is the axiom of choice being invoked in this argument? Is it necessary?

The top answer in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85153/how-do-i-choose-an-element-from-a-non-empty-set) says that we can choose some element from each set in a finite collection of non-empty subsets without choice, though I'm not sure how to do that rigorously. Could some inductive argument be used in the case above?

Comment: it's being used because $A$ is a generic set. If it is finite or countable you don't need it (because $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered)

Comment: @J.G. If $A$ is well-ordered and $S\Subset A$ you can "choose" an element of $S$ without AC, by selecting the smallest element.

Comment: like @DavidC.Ullrich said... and if $A$ is a generic finite/countable set with $f:B\subseteq\Bbb{N}\to A$ bijection you can chose $f(s)$ where $s$ is the least element of $B$

Comment: What everyone has said so far makes sense. Can someone explain why this kind of argument is flawed? For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we know $B_d(x,\frac{1}{n}) \cap A$ is non-empty, i.e. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \exists c : c \in B_d(x,\frac{1}{n}) \cap A$. So by existential instantiation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation),  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : c_n \in B_d(x,\frac{1}{n}) \cap A$, and then we just consider the sequence $\{c_n\}$.

Comment: That sort of argument only uses the definition of non-empty and the rules of first-order logic. Though it seems that we could use it to get around choice in all cases.

Comment: @KeeferRowan, there is a subtlety in your notation. You move from considering $c$ to $c_n$ -- once you adopt the latter notation, you are already suggesting that $c_-$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $A$. For each $n$ you can use existential quantification, but you cannot "gather these together" into a collection or function. In a sense, the axiom of choice is a trick that lets you do lots of instances of existential instantiation simultaneously.

Comment: @KeeferRowan, you might be interested in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839913/axiom-of-choice-where-does-my-argument-for-proving-the-axiom-of-choice-fail-he?rq=1) (with answer and comments).

Comment: @MeesdeVries Ok so we can use existential instantiation a finite number of times to get a choice function on a finite collection of sets, but there is no reason, without a new axiom to allow it, that we can do it infinitely many times, e.g. for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Finally, to clarify, the proof above heavily relies on Choice and no one knows of a non-choice version of the proof? Though clearly countable choice would be sufficient.

Comment: The statement is equivalent to countable choice.